# pip install error when I install fbprophet

Tags: pip, command, facebook-prophet, prophet

(I'm not good at English sorry)
I have an error when I install fbprophet for windows command.
I already installed pystan and cython.

I use Windows 10, python 3.9 version.

maybe, Am I having a problem with the compiler?

The error comment is (korea language in error is not really important thing), -->

=== error in building with wheel ===
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\kstar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\kstar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-la81h33s\fbprophet_b85d314a94fb4910b19f0b36b012fb78\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\kstar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-la81h33s\fbprophet_b85d314a94fb4910b19f0b36b012fb78\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\kstar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-b98qkky1'
cwd: C:\Users\kstar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-la81h33s\fbprophet_b85d314a94fb4910b19f0b36b012fb78
Complete output (44 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\fbprophet
creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.

=== error in running setup.py ===
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: c:\users\kstar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -u -c import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = C:\Users\kstar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-la81h33s\fbprophet_b85d314a94fb4910b19f0b36b012fb78\setup.py; **file**=C:\Users\kstar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-la81h33s\fbprophet_b85d314a94fb4910b19f0b36b012fb78\setup.py;f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open, open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup());code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kstar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-avm6oqpp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\kstar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\fbprophet'
cwd: C:\Users\kstar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-la81h33s\fbprophet_b85d314a94fb4910b19f0b36b012fb78
Complete output (288 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\fbprophet
creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9 NOW.
WARNING:pystan:MSVC compiler is not supported
stanfit4anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9_296405994888268896.cpp
c:\users\kstar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION

Answer (score 0):

following has worked for me before:

```
pip install localpip 
localpip install fbprophet

from fbprophet import Prophet
```